# Why does this function not have any extrema?

Tags: calculus

Why does the following function not have any extrema: $z=(xy-1)^2 +x^2$? I calculated that $\dfrac{dz}{dx}=2((xy-1)y+x)$ and $\dfrac{dz}{dy}=2(xy-1)x$ which are both zero when $x$ and $y$ are zero. What's my mistake?

Comment: Who said it doesn't have any extrema?

Comment: Who said it **must** have an extrema if both partial derivatives of first order vanish??

Comment: @DonAntonio My bad, I forgot to check the second derivatives. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that the function has a *saddle point* there. Check by using the [second partial derivative test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_partial_derivative_test#Functions_of_two_variables).

Comment: Indeed, [plotting the function](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+z%3D%28xy-1%29%5E2%2Bx%5E2+where+-1+%3C+x+%3C+1%2C+-1+%3C+y+%3C+1) shows that there *is* a saddle point.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to check that. Good point!